# What are the main technical differences between Bitcoin-core (BTC), Bitcoin Cash (BCH), and Bitcoin SV (BSV)

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cash, bitcoin-sv

What are the main *technical* differences between Bitcoin-core (BTC), Bitcoin SV (BSV) and Bitcoin Cash (BCH)?

1. At what block number did the fork take place?
2. Do they integrate Segwit/Taproot?
3. What differences are there, if any, in the script instruction set used?
4. Is the address space exactly the same?
5. Is there an estimate for total number of PoW hashes expended on each chain?
6. Are there any other significant differences not covered by the above?

It seems this should be a duplicate, but the only similar I can find is [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/100414/what-is-bitcoin-sv) and [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/87318/what-are-the-major-technical-differences-between-bitcoin-and-bitcoin-cash).

Comment: Hi atomh33ls, thanks for your well-written question. For the past two and a half years, this site has only been covering questions about Bitcoin. Bitcoin Cash and Bitcoin SV are forkcoins that don't fall in the focus of this site. You can find some statistics that compare the three projects for example on https://coin.dance.

Comment: https://bitcoinmagazine.com/technical/infographic-map-bitcoin-forks

Comment: Yes, BSV and Bitcoin Cash created separate cryptocurrency networks with Bitcoin's ledger as their starting point. While they're technologically related and some Bitcoin users may still have some financial interest in them, they're distinct projects with separate issues that are not on-topic here.

Answer (score 5):

> What are the main technical differences between Bitcoin-core (BTC), Bitcoin SV (BSV) and Bitcoin Cash (BCH)?

***BTC* is not Bitcoin Core.**

- *BTC* is the code/symbol/ticker used for the token (currency) bitcoin.
- *bitcoin* is the token (currency) used in Bitcoin, a protocol for decentralized network that allows you to settle payments without trusting third parties.
- *Bitcoin Core* is one of the full node implementations for Bitcoin. Some others are Knots, BTCD, bcoin, gocoin, bitcore, libbitcoin etc.
- *Bitcoin SV* and *Bitcoin Cash* are forks (blockchain) of Bitcoin. I'm not sure if they have stack exchanges or subreddits but questions about other cryptocurrencies are off-topic here.

Comment: Yea Bitcoin Cash has two very strong subreddits. https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoincash/ And https://www.reddit.com/r/btc/